# "Protection Mechanism Failure (CWE ID 693)

Tags: xss, content-security-policy

After security scan, we are seeing the [Protection Mechanism Failure (CWE ID 693)](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/693.html) issue in our application.

Our current header is set as mentioned below-

```
Server: Apache X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 151 Last-Modified: Wed, 04 Apr 2018 08:18:16 GMT
X-Powered-By: Servlet/2.5 JSP/2.1 Content-Security-Policy: default-src
'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *.googleapis.com www.google.com
*.google-analytics.com ; img-src 'self' data: ; Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains;
preload X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block Content-Type: text/html
```

Can you please help to understand how the issue can be resolved? We tried nonce approach also but couldn't get succeed we are left with below issue

> Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following
>   Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self'
>   'nonce-1vb337j47ngp6'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash
>   ('sha256-mf8m/qIWtvEARCPQ2lxzyNeJ+xiFw84zHgmCq5rxqbo='), or a nonce
>   ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.